# Applying matrix on a tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, plot

I would like to apply a matrix (say 1&2\3&4) on a rectangle I drew in tikz. I tried doing so with `cm` but it fails to produce a parallelogram as I expect.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{colorec}{RGB}{51,153,255}
\definecolor{colopa}{RGB}{0,204,102}
\definecolor{arrp}{RGB}{127,0,255}
\draw[fill=colopa,cm={{1,2,3,4},(0,0)}}] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0) ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there any such option in tikz?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation the `cm` arguments have to be passed without curly braces around matrix arguments.
[image: documentation]

The following code works for me:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \definecolor{colopa}{RGB}{0,204,102}

        \draw[fill=colopa,cm={1,2,3,4,(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0) ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks. Actually I have to use expressions with sqrt. don't I need then curly brackets?

Comment: `\draw[fill=colopa,cm={1,sqrt(4),3,4,(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0);` works for me.

Comment: The line I try writng is `\draw[fill=colopa,cm={-1/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(sqrt(3))),1/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(sqrt(3))),-sqrt(sqrt(3))/sqrt(2),-sqrt(sqrt(3))/sqrt(2),(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0) ;` and it still compiles to a rectangle.

Comment: the problem is probably with my first entry. Do you have an idea (it sounds very silly) why TikZ doesn't agree to compile fractions of the form -1/q?

Comment: @DenisMarcinkov are you sure that this is the problem? For me `\draw[fill=colopa,cm={-0.537,0.537,-0.930,-0.930,(0,0)}] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (2,2) -- (0,2) -- (0,0) ;` looks the same. Could it be that you are just calculating the wrong matrix?